# Worthwhile replacing battery of 1st generation iPhone SE?

Tags: iphone, battery

I am considering replacing the battery in my iPhone SE. It drops from 70% charge at room temperature to 10% charge in the outdoor winter cold, then shuts off, leaving me stranded without connectivity.

When I bought the phone several years ago, there was a high profile problem where iOS upgrades would slow the clocks on older phones to make up for the short battery life.  Due to public outcry, Apple agreed to replace the battery for free.  Since I don't use the phone much, I didn't take advantage of that offer initially, and when I decided to, it was too late.

If I replace the battery now, it would likely cost under $100, including tax (about 12% here).  It is a 1st generation iPhone SE [1], however, and I'm not sure how able it will be to host many more iOS upgrades.  At some point, Apple will not allow upgrades in order to avoid untenable customer experiences.

**For those who have visibility into the technology trend, how likely is it that in the next year, the growing procesing/memory demands of iOS upgrades will make them unsupportable by 1st generation iPhone SEs?**

I hardly use the phone (not allowed to have one at work, don't need it at home), so the $150/year of amortized phone cost seems...OK, I suppose.  When I need it, however, I really need it, e.g., navigating a new city, looking up things or communicating when doing milk run activities.

I suppose that it's not the end of the world to be stuck without iOS upgrades, but I anticipate running into problems with web apps and webpage compatibility, as well as stale security.

[1] [Model MP822VC/A](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models)

Comment: I don't think anyone can give a fact-based answer, sadly. No one knows what hardware iOS 15 will support, and if your phone does get dropped, only you can say whether you're okay hanging out on iOS 14. I will tell you that I'm planning to replace _my_ 6S's battery at least one more time, and that's the same processor.

Comment: For sure, i agree.  I was going to "exercise judgement" based on considerations and knowledge that is crowd sourced here.  The fact that you're replacing your battery makes me lean toward doing the same.  Thanks.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy "replace my 6s battery one more time"? I have a 6S plus and it has the original battery and screen. Charged overnight every night and going strong...

Comment: Mine's charges overnight and seemed to be going strong, until I really needed it out in the cold. If I hadn't resorted to barbaric alternatives, my next opportunity to accomplish the task I set out to do would have been next weekend, and I'd be incurring consequences for this throughout the coming week.  So the real issue isn't reliable operation most of the time, it's the flaky operation once I move out of the environment that I'm in most of the time, i.e., the outdoor winter cold.  It wasn't even that cold, possibly warmer than -10 celsius.

Comment: The pundits recently have been speculating the 6S SE etc will be dropped this year - but of course that's also just a guess. @Wowfunhappy - had my 6S battery changed when batterygate [or close equivalent] first happened & they were changing for £30. The 2nd battery was never any better than the one they'd thrown out, still crashes in the cold. Hanging on now til the 13 or SE3… https://www.macrumors.com/2021/01/21/ios-15-drop-support-iphone-6s/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, Apple supports iPhones for seven years—so going from the date it was discontinued in 2018, would give a window of support until 2025. Sometimes, due to specific hardware being able to run later versions of iOS, it may be possible to go beyond that point, but is a gamble.

If you're looking at extending the value, the $100 cost looks like a good deal—as long as you don't need the latest-and-greatest. Keep in mind, though, that the proliferation of 5G networks and changing carrier support may factor into your decision.

Comment: Thanks, that 7-year *rule of thumb* helps.  I don't need the latest and greatest, but the ecosystem of web services might require it by default.  Also, it seems that I should research 5G networks to fathom some possible manifestations of shifting carrier support.  But I'm leaning toward replacing the battery.

Answer (score 0):

While not certain, rumours do seem to suggest that the SE will not make the cut for iOS 15.

https://appleinsider.com/articles/21/01/21/ios-15-will-cut-support-for-iphone-6s-and-original-iphone-se-report-claims

Comment: Thanks, benwiggy.  At that site, mike1 said: "It should be noted that Apple will continue to support the older devices with periodic updates to iOS 14, usually for security reasons for many more years."

Comment: It won't become a doorstop overnight, it will take 3 years or so. If you use it always not too far from a power-supply, in the car for navigation, or for limited periods outdoors then you'll be fine for quite a while. I just never let mine get below 50% charge these days if I'm going to need it. Top it up right before i go out, put it on airplane & low power if I don't expect a call & really need that satnav power to last all day. I have even older iPad & phone that are still good for 'non-modern' work. Don't be forced into upgrading if you don't need to… not sure I'd throw 100 at a battery

Comment: I have the SE myself. I paid for a new battery last year, and it still works well. My upgrade needs are likely to be software driven: if there's a useful new feature in iOS 15 that I could use, or if apps I need require the latest OS, then that will force my hand. Otherwise, "web compatibility" is likely to be OK for one or two years,